# Arrange lookup items in a list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

I have a master list with only `Title` column only. It is having 100 items. Few values are:-

- Communication
- Not Applicable
- Operation

Now, I need "Not Applicable" either at top or at end for my user selection/convenience but "Not Applicable" comes in the middle.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did below answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Use splice method for changing the array.

Refer this link for how splice work

- [splice array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_splice.htm)

Use below typescript/JavaScript to move item 'Not Applicable' at last position.

```
const _options = ['Communication', 'Not Applicable', 'Operation', 'Operation2'];
    
_options.push(_options.splice(_options.indexOf('Not Applicable'), 1)[0]); 
console.log(_options); 

//Out put
// ["Communication", "Operation", "Operation2", "Not Applicable"]
```